# xml string to php page

Tags: php, xml

a photographer here with next to none programming experience. I am working on my website and got far enough (yes, I did a lot of searches) but cannot find the answer. Anybody can point me to the right direction?

I want to generate a code for my galleries. I have several different galleries/pages, and I would like to store all src, alt in one xml file, then bring it to a specific page.

SO far I have this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <img id="pf01">
      <src>foodphotography/01</src>
      <alt>food1</alt>
   </img>
   <img id="pf02">
      <src>foodphotography/01</src>
      <alt>food2</alt>
   </img>
   <pf id="pf03">
      <src>foodphotography/05</src>
      <alt>food2</alt>
   </pf>
</catalog>
```

and the php code

```
<?php
    // Loading the XML file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("img.xml");
    foreach($xml->children() as $img)
    {
        echo "<div class='swiper-slide'>\n";
        echo "<img src='/images/".$img->src."'     alt='".$img->alt."'>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
?>
```

I am trying to display on one page only `<img>` and on the other `<pf>`. Right now it displays all 3 images. How do I pick from the xml file only specific images? It looks like I cannot have more than one catalog.

Any better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Xslt perhaps? Some good resources if you Google it

Comment: Can you clarify how you intend to pick the files? Right now you are iterating over all the img elements and echo them. Consequently, they will all show up. [You can pick specific elements via the xpath method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) or by comparing the SimpleXml elements. But we do not know how you identify pages.

Comment: On one page I would like to display only "img", or the other only "pf". Right now it does display all 3 in the catalog, but ideally it would display 2 on one page, and 1 on the other page by picking them up by the img, pf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of way you could filter on this, but since you're interested in having them on different pages, then you might just use [`xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to filter the children. So to just show the `img` use the xpath `/document/img`

```
<?php
// Loading the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("img.xml");

// swap children for xpath
foreach($xml->xpath('/catalog/img') as $img)
{
    echo "<div class='swiper-slide'>\n";
    echo "<img src='/images/".$img->src."'     alt='".$img->alt."'>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
}
```

And on your other page, use the xpath `/catalog/pf`